# Removed NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

Here I can use `NSUserDefaults`, but I need to `remove` this `NSUserDefaults`.
In my app I'm using `NSUserDefaults` for getting locations one `View` to `anotherView` but here issue when I'm closed to the my app, and again I started still the locations are there, here I used for removing locations in `AppDeligate`

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"Location"];
}
```

But still locations is there.
How can I removed this?
Can you suggest me.

Comment: Below it write 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your method

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"Location"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

into

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{


  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"Location"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

whenever you remove or add values in  `NSUserDefaults` don't forget to call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`, if your fetching the values on that time no need to add `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

Comment: u can clear your NSUserDefaults in  2 ways, one applicationWillTerminate another one didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called at initial time only

Comment: your coding is fine , need to change your method

Comment: have a happy day my friend